# JUnit in Android Studio isn't using currency formatting correctly

Tags: java, junit, android-studio, junit4, currency-formatting

Note: I'm using the setup Google now [recommends](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) for doing JUnit testing in Android Studio.

I'm trying to do unit testing on a piece of code which stores a currency value as a double and outputs a string in the format of that currency. I use `java.text.NumberFormat` to do this:

```
public NumberFormat viewFormat;
public NumberFormat editFormat;

public CurrencyField(String languageCode, String countryCode) {
    viewFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale(languageCode, countryCode));
    viewFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
```

Here's where I get the value I want to be formatted for display:

```
public String getDisplayValue()
{
    double numberValue = (double) mValue.getValue();
    return mField.viewFormat.format(numberValue);
}
```

When I run the code as part of the Android app, the number is formatted correctly. For example, if I am using the Israeli shekel as my currency, I call

```
Field currencyField = new CurrencyField("he", "ISR");
```

where `"he"` and `"ISR"` are the the codes for Hebrew and Israel, respectively. If the number is stored internally as the double `45.12`, it is output as the string `"45.12 ₪"`, which is correct. However, when I try to run the same code using JUnit, here's what the test outputs:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure:  
Expected :45.12 ₪  
Actual   :¤ 45.12
```

It seems to me that JUnit or Android Studio is somehow missing some Java libraries during testing. I wasn't even able to get the shekel symbol programmatically for the expected value. I tried to use `java.util.Currency`, and that didn't work, and then I tried

```
expectedDisplayValue += ((CurrencyField) field).viewFormat.getCurrency().getSymbol(new Locale("he", "ISR"));
```

and that didn't work either. I had to explicitly define

```
private String expectedDisplayValue = "45.12 ₪";
```

Why does the formatting work at runtime, but not in the test?

Comment: I'm guessing that the locale isn't being set in JUnit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was using the wrong ISO 3166-1 country code. I was using the alpha 3 code ("ISR") instead of the alpha 2 code ("IL"), which worked in the app but not in the test. The test still gives me the wrong symbol and formatting when I use Hebrew, but I'll ask a separate question for that. In the meantime, I'll use some other foreign currency for testing.